# Stuck creating a 0/1 flag that works correctly. Finally giving in

Tags: mysql, case

Evening all.

I am trying to create a very basic case statement which buckets three scenarios with a 0 or a 1 in mySQL.
I have three fields found in the reference table link below.

Essentially I am trying to bucket any ProductID that has a StatusCD of 'I' and 'O' as 1, only 'I' as 1 and then anything with only an 'O' result and no corresponding 'I' as a 0. What this data is showing is a product coming into the warehouse ('I') and then exiting the warehouse ('O'). I have other fields which are capturing date differences but ultimately I am trying to create a flag to ignore scenarios where we only have Product#'s with an 'O' statusCD which would indicate their arrival to the warehouse was not logged appropriately and would skew our "Age in warehouse" buckets.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Reference Table with fields:

```
Date       | ProductID | StatusCD
2021-01-01 | U1000     | I
2021-01-10 | U1000     | O
2021-01-10 | U2000     | I
2021-01-15 | U3000     | O
```

Comment: so what you're trying to do is to get the productID with in and out and disregard the productID without in?

Comment: Almost. I want to flag a productID with an In only, or an In and Out with a 1, and flag the Out only, with no In date, with a 0. I am determining the # of days in the warehouse and ignore those that have an Out only flag in the system. I know this has to be super simple and I must be overthinking it.

Comment: it isn't clear what you want the results to look like; show example results for your sample data

Comment: also, you say "and no corresponding 'I'"; do you mean with any date? or are there restrictions on what counts as "corresponding"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to retain every original record, you could use analytic functions here:

```sql
SELECT Date, ProductID, StatusCD,
       CASE WHEN SUM(StatusCD <> 'O') OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID) = 0
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As Label
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

For versions of MySQL earlier than 8+:

```sql
SELECT t1.Date, t1.ProductID, t1.StatusCD,
       CASE WHEN t2.OpenCount = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Label
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ProductID, SUM(StatusCD <> 'O') AS OpenCount
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ProductID
) t2
    ON t2.ProductID = t1.ProductID
ORDER BY
    t1.Date;
```

### Demo

Comment: Okay. So this works in Fiddle but for some reason when I write out this snippet, my MySQL is not working correctly and it just keeps saying "select is not valid at this position for this server version." That's a first for me. I am using MySQL 8.022 workbench.

Comment: @Venture-MTB Your Workbench version is largely irrelevant. Your MySQL engine version is relevant, and it's probably 5.7, which is why my query isn't working for you.  I just added a workaround which should work on your earlier version of MySQL.

Comment: yes, run `select version();` to see your server's version

Comment: 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log, 5.7, Tim was correct

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was able to get your version working in Fiddle in your demo, however, when I add that bit of code and adjust to my actual table names, while it runs, it spits out a duplicate. So I am getting four rows for ProductID: U1000 and I am returning a version with both a 0, and a 1 assigned to each status. Tried select distinct inside and out of the join, no go.

Comment: I can't help much unfortunately, because I built my answer around the sample data you actually gave us.  It sounds like your real data has some caveats which were not mentioned.

Comment: It appears so. I think we're going to need to create a secondary view or do some additional cleaning. I pointed our architect to this page and your response with the links to Fiddle to show him what we are trying to accomplish. Thank you for your assistance tonight. Have a great evening.

Comment: @Venture-MTB What you described two comments above sounds like the flag isn't just per product, is per product _and_ some other column.  In any case, feel free to open another question, but do include the real data so that others may give you the best answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just spoke with our architect. Looks like the view he created did not have the Product ID's down to 1 ID per date, thus having duplicate rows. He repopulated and deduped the view, I re-ran and got the appropriate result set. Thank you again.